# IQueueProcessorFactory on Azure WebJobs 3.0?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

With **Azure WebJobs 2.0** to implement an instance of `IQueueProcessorFactory` I have to do something like this:

```
_jobHostConfiguration = new JobHostConfiguration {
        StorageConnectionString = "XXX"
        DashboardConnectionString = "XXX"                
        };
_jobHostConfiguration.Queues.QueueProcessorFactory = new CustomQueueProcessorFactory();
```

Where `CustomQueueProcessorFactory` is something like this:

```
public class CustomQueueProcessorFactory: IQueueProcessorFactory
{
    public QueueProcessor Create(QueueProcessorFactoryContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        if (context.Queue.Name.Equals("queue_A") {
            context.BatchSize = 32; 
            context.NewBatchThreshold = 100;
        } 

        if (context.Queue.Name.Equals("queue_B")) {
            context.BatchSize = 2; 
        } 

        return new QueueProcessor(context);
    }        
}
```

My question is: how can I do the same with **Azure WebJobs 3.0**?

I can't find any sample.

Answer (score 4):

In Webjob 3.0 the attribute `QueuesOptions` in `AddAzureStorage` do not have QueueProcessorFactory.

So, you could use `builder.ConfigureServices(s => s.AddSingleton<IQueueProcessorFactory>(factory));` to inject `IQueueProcessorFactory`. Please refer to the steps as below:

1.Program.cs.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new HostBuilder();
        var factory = new CustomQueueProcessorFactory();
        builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
        {
            b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
            b.AddAzureStorage();
        });
        builder.ConfigureServices(s => s.AddSingleton<IQueueProcessorFactory>(factory));
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
        });
        var host = builder.Build();
        using (host)
        {
            host.Run();
        }
    }
}

public class CustomQueueProcessorFactory : IQueueProcessorFactory
{
    public QueueProcessor Create(QueueProcessorFactoryContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }
        if (context.Queue.Name.ToString() == "queue")
        {
            context.MaxDequeueCount = 10;
        }
        else if (context.Queue.Name.ToString() == "queue1")
        {
            context.MaxDequeueCount = 10;
            context.BatchSize = 1;
        }
        return new QueueProcessor(context);
    }
}
```

2.Function.cs:

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue1")] string message, TextWriter log)
{
    log.WriteLine(message);
}
```